# Show that if an open ball is not the total space then...

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How could I solve the following exercise?

I'm not actually sure whether I understand what it is asking me to do.
"Given a metric space $(X, d)$, $x \in X$ and $r>0$; show that if the ball $B(x;r)$ is not the total space then $d(x, X-B(x;r))>=r$"

Thank you!

Comment: The expression $d(x,X-B(x;r))$ is the distance from a point to a set; do you know this definition?

Answer (score 1):

For any $z \in X-B(x;r)$ we have that $r\le d(x,z)$ (or else $d(z,x) < r$ and $z \in B(x;r)$ which is not the case), so $r$ is **a** lower bound of 
$\{d(x,z): z \in X-B(x;r)\}$ and as the infimum is the *largest* bound of that set by definition $d(x, X-B(X;r)) = \inf \{d(x,z): z \in X-B(x;r)\} \ge r$ as required.

I think the condition that $B(x;r)$ was added to ensure that the set $\{d(x,z): z \in X-B(x;r)\}$ is non-empty, but that is actually unnecessary as by convention $\inf \emptyset = +\infty > r$ anyway.